# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in cms.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, umbraco, asp.net-4.0

Trying to go to a page on my site, got a blank screen and decided to try again with Visual Studio 2012 loaded and debugging it, now I get this error when the page loads:

`An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in cms.dll but was not handled in user code` and points to the following code in `HeaderControl.ascx.cs`:

```
else if(new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.template.Template((Context.GetContent()).template).Alias == "TemplateLanguage")
```

This code is inside the following method:

```
public void LoadData()
{
    _Location = HttpContext.Current.GetLocation();

    if (Context.GetContent().NodeTypeAlias == "Home")
    {
        TheHomeHeaderPH.Visible = true;
        ThePhonePH.Visible      = true;
        _MenuStyle = "var-nav nav-large";
        LoadMenuTopControl();
        LoadMenuMainControl();
    }  
    else if(new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.template.Template((Context.GetContent()).template).Alias == "TemplateLanguage") 
    {
        TheContentHeaderPH.Visible = true;
        _MenuStyle              = "nav-small";
        LoadContentMenuTopControl();
        LoadMenuLanguageControl();
    }
    else
    {
        MMG.BusinessLayer.Content theContent = MMG.BusinessLayer.Content.GetCached(Context.GetContent());

        if (theContent.TemplateColor == "168C9C")
        {
            TheHomeHeaderPH.Visible = true;
            _MenuStyle = "nav-small";
            LoadMenuTopControl();
            LoadMenuMainControl();
        }
        else
        {
            TheContentHeaderPH.Visible = true;
            LoadContentMenuTopControl();
            LoadContentMenuMainControl();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?  `System.ArgumentException` says this: `{"No node exists with id '0'"}`

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess it's the `(Context.GetContent()).template` that breaks somehow and I assume `GetContent` is a custom extension method.

The exception `{"No node exists with id '0'"}` usually means that you couldn't fetch the node you requested.

Instead try

```
else if(new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.template.Template(umbraco.uQuery.GetCurrentNode().template).Alias == "TemplateLanguage")
```

If that doesn't work it means you are running the code in a context where the CurrentNode is unavailable. In that case you must extend your LoadData method with a nodeId parameter.